# cUrl keeps following location header

Tags: php, redirect, curl

Okay I post 2 fields to a url using cUrl, this page checks my post fields and based on them it returns me cookies. However before i can even read the cookies I'm already redirected to an other page.
I tried setting _FOLLOWLOCATION, 0 but I'm still getting redirected. Are there any thoughts on this?
Code:

```
$headers[] = "Accept: */*";
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
$headers[] = "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";

$fields_string = "login_url=/login.do?school=windesheim";
$fields_string=rtrim($fields_string, "&");
$cSession = curl_init(); 
$tmpfname = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie2.txt';
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_REFERER,  "https://website.com/login.do?error=nomandant");
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers)
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfname);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"https://website.com/j_spring_security_check");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt ($cSession, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($cSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
curl_close($cSession);
echo htmlspecialchars($result);
```

If I print the header it says location: https://website.com/login.do?error=nomandant

So I go to this page, I can't get the cookies because I'm redirected to the next page which then redirects me back to the first page because I don't have the cookies set.
  I want to get on the first page, don't be redirected, and read the cookies from the header.
How come that I'm being redirected even though followlocation is set to 0/false?

Update:
When I'm in my browser at website.com and I enter Windesheim in postfield and post it this it posts to /j_spring_security_check

[image: browser network inspector]

So i try to simulate this using cUrl using the code from above (updated with more info). But the output is only:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Length: 0 
Date: Sat, 16 Nov 2013 14:28:33 GMT 
Location: https://website.com/login.do?error=nomandant Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

The expected result is something like the response header in the picture above.
So something is going wrong that it is redirecting me to

```
/login.do?error=nomandant
```

instead of

```
/index.do;jsessionid=etc.
```

But I can't figure out what I am doing wrong as there are only 2 field being posted and I included them both in my code.

Comment: it is a bit unclear, is your _browser_ being redirected, or the curl session defined as `$cSession`? If it is the _browser_, there must be some other code going on that you're not showing us, if it is `$cSession`... well... `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` will work. How are you inspecting `$result`? If you're dumping it to the browser use `echo htmlspecialchars($result);` so no client-side code is executed.

Comment: The $cSession is being redirected. I just tried echo htmlspecialchars($result); It gave me the same output

Comment: Also maybe it's usefull to say that when I inspect the page /j_spring_security_check using google chrome console it gives a status code: 302 Found. Could it have anything to do with the redirect, even though followlocation is set to false?

Comment: Plain and simple, when `CURLOP_FOLLOWLOCATION` is `false` (try setting to `(boolean) false`, instead of `0`, don't think it matters though), `Location:`  is not honored. You could even try setting `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` to `(int) 0`.
If all else fails, I'd suggest making an update that uses [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions).

Answer (score 1):

First, note that you'll be able to read cookies after the session is closed with curl_close.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

From what you say you're actually being redirected by the server to another location, but curl is **not following** that location. This is the reason you see an header with a redirection.

curl is behaving as expected!

If you set it to follow the new location you would see the haeder and the page **at the new location** https://website.com/login.do?error=nomandant

Given the data you're posting to the URL the server wants to send you back to https://website.com/login.do?error=nomandant

If this is not what you expect either the cookies you're sending with the request are not good (for example missing session value...) or you're posting the wrong data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you take a look at my update post? Thanks!

Comment: you're not sending to https://website.com/j_spring_security_check the data (post or cookies) it expects. can't tell what from you're screenshot. Try with firefox and livehttpheaders plugin: you see everything that is going back and forth between browser and server

Comment: It shows the same data, login_url and school. Anyway thanks for your time! +1 for the effort